# Does visiting cached pages disclose my IP address to site admin?

Tags: web-browser, internet, caching

I know it discloses my IP to Google,
but is my IP also disclosed to the owner of the site of which Google made cached pages that I'm looking at?

And how about anything I do within the cached page - like copying a URL or email address off it (by just holding down or right clicking on the blue hypertext to copy, and not clicking that would open the URL or activate Email application!) - does that give my IP to the original site?

Answer (score 3):

The cached page still contains references to the original content (images, scripts and style-sheet files, etc.) so, when you look at the default cached page, your browser will request this content to the original website, possibly along with a "referer" header telling explicitely to the website that you are currently viewing the Google cached version of which page.

However Google offers you the alternative to see the "Text-only version" of the cached page. By this way all these tags linking to the original content will be stripped off and your browser will contact only Google servers.

And as per you second question, all your interaction with the text-only version of the cached page will remain local to your browser: you can right-click, select, copy, save or examine the source code of the whole web page or a some elements of them freely.

***Foot note***: the above statement is true for a "normal" behaving browser and environment. Some browser plugins and antivirus proactively check the links contained on a webpage displayed in the browser without the user having to click on them (use case can range from checking the URL reputation to actually downloading the web page to accelerate navigation). You should know if your system has got such feature installed on it. In case of doubt, a simple test with a network monitoring tool like Wireshark would tell.

Comment: Wireshark is better for verification but if you can't install something: Quick network checks within browsers include: opening their developer consoles (to the network tab, for Firefox and Chrome) and monitoring their sockets (chrome://net-internals/#sockets and about:networking in Firefox).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention all this is on iPad! So no wireshark or developer consoles. Should I still check with something else? I didn't really understand about the Footnote. So if browser plugins and antivirus automatically check links contained in a page, that could send my IP to the site owner, is what you mean? Thanks

Comment: The foot note was merely to take care of unusual cases. Under normal circumstances, you can assume that when using the text-only version of the cached page your browser will not contact any other server than the one from Google. In unusual cases, everything is possible so yes, third-party plugins or software may still get in touch with the site owner. If you need 100% certainty, then you may want to take unusual cases into account and check for such background activity. Otherwise, usual case should just be fine and you can skip the foot note.